# "Adaptive Skin" in Blender

Tags: modifiers, objects, topology

Zbrush has a feature where multiple objects are merged together into one smooth collective shape with decent topology, called adaptive skin.

I tried Googling a way to do this in Blender, but no luck. Asking here in case I missed a key word or such.

A modifier would be best if possible, since it would be useful for simulating a morphing blob.